# Diagnosing a service not starting on reboot (Calibre eBook)

Tags: systemd, calibre

I'm trying to figure out why a couple of my services aren't starting up at reboot. Once the system is up and running, I can run the service without issue.

**/var/log/error.log**

```
Nov 16 04:01:31 Ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Calibre eBook Server.
```

**cat /lib/systemd/system/calibre.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Calibre eBook Server
Documentation=https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-calibre-ebook-server-on-ubuntu-14-04
After=network.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=calibre
Group=calibre
PIDFile=/var/run/calibre/calibre-server.pid
RuntimeDirectory=calibre
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0750
ExecStart=/opt/calibre/calibre-server \
        --daemonize \
        --max-opds-items=100 \
        --max-opds-ungrouped-items=100 \
        --url-prefix /calibre \
        --pidfile=/var/run/calibre/calibre-server.pid \
        --port=8080 \
        --listen-on=192.168.0.199 \
        --log="/var/log/mediaservers/calibre/calibre.log" \
        "/media/eBooks/"
#       "/media/eBooks/"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**journalctl -b e91fd44ec7d848aab748c9f63778f54e -u calibre.service**

```
Nov 16 04:01:28 Ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Calibre eBook Server...
Nov 16 04:01:31 Ubuntu calibre-server[2163]: There is no calibre library at: /media/eBooks/
Nov 16 04:01:31 Ubuntu systemd[1]: calibre.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 16 04:01:31 Ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Calibre eBook Server.
Nov 16 04:01:31 Ubuntu systemd[1]: calibre.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 16 04:01:31 Ubuntu systemd[1]: calibre.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**journalctl -b e91fd44ec7d848aab748c9f63778f54e | grep -i calibre**

```
(standard input):1376:Nov 16 04:01:28 Ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Calibre eBook Server...
(standard input):1662:Nov 16 04:01:31 Ubuntu calibre-server[2163]: There is no calibre library at: /media/eBooks/
(standard input):1663:Nov 16 04:01:31 Ubuntu systemd[1]: calibre.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
(standard input):1664:Nov 16 04:01:31 Ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Calibre eBook Server.
(standard input):1665:Nov 16 04:01:31 Ubuntu audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=calibre comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=?
 res=failed'
(standard input):1666:Nov 16 04:01:31 Ubuntu systemd[1]: calibre.service: Unit entered failed state.
(standard input):1668:Nov 16 04:01:31 Ubuntu systemd[1]: calibre.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**ls -al /media**

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Apr 12  2018 /media -> /mnt/SG-8TB-1/Media/
```

**ls -al /media/| grep eBooks**

```
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root      root          27 May  9  2018 eBooks -> /mnt/SG-6TB-2/Media/eBooks/
```

**cat /etc/fstab**

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1                          none            swap    sw                                      0       0
UUID=edb48d14-df73-4efb-8808-92d2c705741f       /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,defaults,acl          0       1
UUID=e6c06084-4453-43b8-ae97-cbef4d9c5f6f       /tmp            ext4    errors=remount-ro,defaults,acl,noatime  0       2
UUID=0cb84aea-291c-4637-bcbc-d543e53b711e       /var            ext4    errors=remount-ro,defaults,acl,nofail   0       2
UUID=51b8dc62-a9e9-4c7e-9e94-32ae8109d62b       /home           ext4    errors=remount-ro,defaults,acl,nofail   0       2

UUID=f3ce7d6d-7543-4cd8-991c-4f6c427f18c5       /mnt/SG-1.5TB-1 ext4    errors=remount-ro,defaults,acl,nofail   0       3

UUID=4e16cf60-13ee-452f-a67f-e989032dcf7d       /mnt/SG-3TB-1   ext4    errors=remount-ro,defaults,acl,nofail   0       3

UUID=d834fa15-c81c-4330-b40e-b04e2cd5471f       /mnt/SG-4TB-1   ext4    errors=remount-ro,defaults,acl,nofail   0       3
UUID=ce1c1da3-fee5-4020-8361-e94f9a106c80       /mnt/SG-4TB-2   ext4    errors=remount-ro,defaults,acl,nofail   0       3
#UUID=883d1bdf-b06d-4865-b64f-f0c44d66ab62      /mnt/SG-4TB-3   ext4    errors=remount-ro,defaults,nofail       0       4

UUID=a8d31f58-54e6-4867-8833-c9a3c323f105       /mnt/SG-6TB-1   ext4    errors=remount-ro,defaults,acl,nofail   0       3
UUID=3ffb6832-f412-43bd-b984-0aad7dd16cd0       /mnt/SG-6TB-2   ext4    errors=remount-ro,defaults,acl,nofail   0       3

UUID=3602d0dc-8fa0-40bd-9ebe-b8dec16fc1da       /mnt/SG-8TB-1   ext4    errors=remount-ro,defaults,acl,nofail   0       3
UUID=59c19339-fdf1-40ef-b802-33c3c8f7e670       /mnt/SG-8TB-2   ext4    errors=remount-ro,defaults,acl,nofail   0       3
UUID=e9d6ec8c-c519-4d00-88e4-79b22d11b0ec       /mnt/SG-8TB-3   ext4    errors=remount-ro,defaults,acl,nofail   0       3

UUID=ba9d87b3-09c2-4cee-ab6a-eb73110d50f0       /mnt/WD-2TB-1   ext4    errors=remount-ro,defaults,acl,nofail   0       3
```

Comment: /media points to /mnt/SG-**8TB**-1/Media/ but that drive isn't listed in fstab, what is that?

Comment: I had snipped the fstab file and forgot to leave that in - I've updated the post with the full fstab.  Sorry about that.